# How to save a file offset to use it later using system calls

Tags: c, linux, file, system-calls

I'm managing files in C using only system calls and I'm creating a method, let's call it "make_backup", where does a backup of a file and change it.
This file is composed by binary structed entries, like a database.
So, the next time I call "make_backup", I need make that backup where the last finished.

My logic to do this is to save the size of file in the first "make_backup" call and access it in the second call. But the problem I'm forbidden to write this off_s into a other/same file.

I try doing a hole of 5 bytes with `ftruncate` in the end of the file in the first call. In the second call, using lseek with SEEK_HOLE to find that offset+5 and `fallocate w/ FALLOC_FL_COLLAPSE_RANGE` to remove that hole. But the `SEEK_HOLE` offset is always the EOF.

The second try was using somehow file description flags like `fcntl(fd, F_SET_FILE_RW_HINT,offset)`, but no luck.

```c
#define LEN_HOLE 5
int fd = open ("file.bin", O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_PATH | O_DIRECT, 0777);

off_t size = lseek (fd,0,SEEK_END);
off_t hole = lseek(fd,0,SEEK_HOLE);

ftruncate(fd,size+LEN_HOLE);

if(size==hole) return hole;

fallocate(fd, FALLOC_FL_COLLAPSE_RANGE, hole, LEN_HOLE);

///// or /////

uint64_t hint;
int ret;

ret = fcntl(fd, F_GET_FILE_RW_HINT, &hint);
if (ret < 0) {
    perror("fcntl: F_GET_FILE_RW_HINT");
    return -1;
}

uint64_t set_hint = (uint64_t) size;
ret = fcntl(fd, F_SET_FILE_RW_HINT, &set_hint);
if (ret < 0) {
    perror("fcntl: F_SET_FILE_RW_HINT");
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: You should check the return values of `ftruncate()` and `fallocate()` to see if there is a failure or not.

Comment: Sorry, it's Linux and the return values are successful on the both

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're trying to do here. Who has "forbidden" you from writing the size of a file to the backup file? What is the expected structure of the resulting file? Using fragile forms of metadata like file holes is not a good idea; these types of metadata are easily lost during file copying and archiving operations.